# Getting the count of subcategories in a table grouped by categories and subcategories in `SQLite`

Tags: sqlite, join, group-by, count, cross-join

I have the following `Loans` table:

```
EmployeeId  LoanCatId   LoanSubCatId    LoanDate
------------------------------------------------
1           4           1               19990125
3           3           2               20101210
6           1           1               19910224
4           4           2               20120219
1           3           1               19920214
2           4           2               19930614
1           3           2               19840705
6           1           1               20030917
5           1           1               19900204
3           1           2               20181113
```

where the fields `EmployeeId`, `LoanCatId`, and `LoanSubCatId` reference the ID of the following tables, as foreign keys, respectively:

Table `Employees`:

```
EmployeeId  Name
------------------
1           John
2           Jack
3           Alex
4           Fred
5           Danny
6           Russel
```

Table `LoanCategories`:

```
CategoryId  CategoryName
------------------------
1           CA
2           CB
3           CC
4           CD
```

Table `LoanSubCategories`:

```
CategoryId  CategoryName
------------------------
1           SCA
2           SCB
```

I'm trying to get the following table by specifying a `LoanDate` for example, '19990125' (the first row in the `Loans` table):

```
CategoryName    SubCategoryName Count
-------------------------------------
CA              SCA             0
CA              SCB             0
CB              SCA             0
CB              SCB             0
CC              SCA             0
CC              SCB             0
CD              SCA             1
CD              SCB             0
```

The database is `SQLite`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of `LoanCategories` and `LoanSubCategories` to get all the combinations of categories and subcategories and a `LEFT` join to `Loans` for the specific date that you want.
Finally, you must aggregate for each category/subcategory:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName, 
       s.CategoryName AS SubCategoryName,
       COUNT(l.LoanDate) AS Count
FROM LoanCategories c CROSS JOIN LoanSubCategories s
LEFT JOIN Loans l ON l.LoanCatId = c.CategoryId AND l.LoanSubCatId = s.CategoryId AND l.LoanDate = '19990125'
GROUP BY c.CategoryId, s.CategoryId;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hZFqcXiH).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` on the categories tables to obtain all possible combinations, and `right join` to combine the data, and conditional aggregation to obtain the desired outcome.

```
select s.catName, s.subCatName, count(case when l.LoanDate = 19990125 then 1 end) as count_
from Loans l
inner join Employees e on e.EmployeeId = l.EmployeeId 
right join (
  select c.CategoryId as catId, c.CategoryName as catName, s.CategoryId as subCatId, s.CategoryName as subCatName
  FROM LoanCategories c 
  CROSS JOIN LoanSubCategories s 
) as s on s.catId = l.LoanCatId and s.subCatId = l.LoanSubCatId
group by s.catId, s.subCatId
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cWYt4dmi)